# Detect middle mouse click event

Tags: c++, events, event-handling, mouseevent, mouseclick-event

I need to detect a middle mouse click event in C++. Does anyone know how I can do so? If there is a way, can someone tell me how I can do it? I'm not so familiar with mouse events in C++. Seems a bit more complicated to do it in C++ as oppose to Java.

Comment: It depends on the environment you're working in. What is it?

Comment: I'm working in Windows environment and no I just want to detect the event strictly using C++ and no OpenGL library.

Comment: C++ language doesn't have any GUI related functions. Your options are WIN32 API, MFC, QT and OpenGL (probably other libs too). The last 2 are cross platform.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are working on windows the following may work for you:
If your application contains a window, then simply look for [WM_MBUTTONDOWN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms645610%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) in your message loop.
If you dont have a window, then you can use a [mouse hook](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644988%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).
Where you check the wParam for WM_MBUTTONDOWN(or WM_BUTTONUP).